Looking for customization in stocktools shapes option popup
I'm using highcharts with stocktools. In the stocktools shapes I want to customize shapes options, specifically fill color or line color. Instead of rgba value, I want to add predefined list of colors.

Here i'm providing my expectation through image. The predefined list of color customization in stocktools shapes popup options.


As for now, there is no easy way to achieve that in Stock without overwriting a bunch of code. There is a little PoC which you can check over here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5wdyuk8v/
But keep in mind that it will only work for solid colors (does not support opacity).
const types = Highcharts._modules['Extensions/Annotations/NavigationBindingsUtilities.js'].annotationsFieldsTypes;

types.color = types.backgroundColor = types.borderColor = types.stroke = types.fill = 'color';

function getType(key, value) {
  const predefinedType = types[key];
  let fieldType = typeof value;
  if (Highcharts.defined(predefinedType)) {
    fieldType = predefinedType;
  }
  return {
    'string': 'text',
    'number': 'number',
    'boolean': 'checkbox',
    'color': 'color' // fix
  } [fieldType];
};

Highcharts.addEvent(

  Highcharts._modules['Extensions/Annotations/NavigationBindings.js'],
  'showPopup',
  function(e) {
    function traverse(options) {
      for (const [key, option] of Object.entries(options)) {
        if (Highcharts.isObject(option, true)) {
          traverse(option);
        } else if (Highcharts.isArray(option)) {
          if (typeof option[1] === 'undefined') {
            option[1] = getType(key, option[0]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    traverse(e.options);
  }, {
    order: 0
  }
);


Actully I able to manage to open custom popup. And everything is working such as change shapes line color, fill and line width. This only problem I have which is when I click to edit shapes button then both custom popup and default popup both are showing. I want to remove default popup fully from dom tree.
const defaultPopup = document.querySelector('.highcharts-popup.highcharts-no-tooltip:not(.highcharts-annotation-toolbar)');
if (defaultPopup) {
defaultPopup.remove();
}

I tried the mentioned code to remove the default popup. it's working for the first time but after second click in shape highcharts-annotation-toolbar itself not showing.
